# In azure how to concatenate strings in a summarize statement?

Tags: azure, logging, azure-log-analytics

I have a statement where I try to concatenate logs (strings) together to a single string.

Something like this

```
ContainerLog
| where conditions
| summarize strcat(LogEntry)
```

However I cant figure out how to concatenate strings like this since strcat is not an aggregating function. I need something else but don't know what.

How can I do this?

For example if I have log entries "1","2","3" the final result should be "123"

Answer (score 9):

This allows a distinct combination in concrete.

```
requests
| where URL contains "prod"
| summarize count(), code=make_set(resultCode) by name
| sort by count_ desc
```

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/makeset-aggfunction

Comment: To make this answer complete (I assume you wanted to have string as a result) you have to join at the end:
```
requests
| where URL contains "prod"
| summarize count(), code=make_set(resultCode) by name
| extend code=strcat_array(code, ", ")
| sort by count_ desc
```